# Force EF Core TPT : Stamping every table with same field? (duplicate field in base and derived table)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

With TPT i want to duplicate the ChangedDate information also
in the Table2 Employee (its possible that just that table gets changed later..)

How is it possible to "force" EF Core that the Field "Createddate" is in the Base table AND in the inherited table? by specifying it in the configation its not working.
The insert always failes in the Employee table because EF Core does not specify the not nullable ChangedDate Column in the insert query.
The insert on Person Table works.

## SQL Schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Person](
    [PersonId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name1] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [ChangedDate] datetime NOT NULL
)`

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Employee](
    [PersonId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ChangedDate] datetime NOT NULL
)
```

## EF Model

```
public abstract class TblPerson 
    {
        public long PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangedDate{ get; set; }
}

public class TblEmployee : TblPerson 
    {
        public DateTime ChangedDate{ get; set; }
}
```

## EF Configuration

```
    public class TblEmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TblEmployee >
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TblEmployee > builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("tbl_Employee", "dbo");
            builder.HasBaseType<TblEmployee >();
            builder.Property(x =>      x.PersonId).HasColumnName(@"PersonId").HasColumnType("bigint").IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd().Us eIdentityColumn();
             builder.Property(x =>  x.ChangedDate).HasColumnName(@"ChangedDate").HasColumnType("datetime").IsRequired();
  }

 public class TblPerson : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TblPerson>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TblPerson> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("tbl_Person", "dbo");
            builder.HasBaseType<TblPerson>();
            builder.Property(x =>  x.PersonId).HasColumnName(@"PersonId").HasColumnType("bigint").IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd().Us eIdentityColumn();
             builder.Property(x =>  x.ChangedDate).HasColumnName(@"ChangedDate").HasColumnType("datetime").IsRequired();
  }
```

## Wrong Query generated

```
    exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Person] ([PersonId])
    VALUES (@p24);
    ',N'@p24 bigint',@p24=6000196
```

## Expected Query to be generated

```
    exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Person] ([PersonId], [ChangedDate])
    VALUES (@p24, @p25);
    ',N'@p24 bigint,@p25 datetime',@p24=6000196,@p25='2022-11-15 10:40:31.953
```

Comment: Why do you want two `ChangedDate` properties on the `TblEmployee` entity? Why do you not want to use the already existing `ChangedDate` property from the `TblPerson`? That sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] your question to include the actual problem you try to solve. Having two properties with the same name is not the solution, but instead leads to huge confusions.

Comment: yes, your comment sound correct, but anyway there is the case that a background process changes a field in the employee table (eg. hire date) but tha person table should not be affected because there should be the change date if the (eg name) propety changed of the person table.